# Click to change images with an ease transition

Tags: javascript, transition, fadein

I have a hero image that changes with the click of an arrow button (previous / next). This part works well, however the change is sharp. I'm trying to add an ease transition between each image so that they quickly fade in or out. Is there a simple way to do this using the JS below? I'm a beginner. Thanks!

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var images = [
            "tophalf-b.jpg",
            "tophalf-a.jpg",    
        ];

        var imageIndex = 0;

        $("#previous").on("click", function(){          
            imageIndex = (imageIndex + images.length -1) % (images.length);    
            $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

        });

        $("#next").on("click", function(){
            imageIndex = (imageIndex+1) % (images.length);    
            $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

        });

        $("#image").attr(images[0]);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#image").attr(images[0]);` ... you mean: `$("#image").attr("src", images[0]);` (you're missing the actual **attribute** you want to change!)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
$("#previous").on("click", function(){          
    $("#image").fadeOut(500, (function() {
        imageIndex = (imageIndex + images.length -1) % (images.length);                
        $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
    }));            
    $("#image").fadeIn();
});
```

`500` is a time of animation. Next, the callback function where we change the image. Finally, fade in image element.

If you want a 'crossfade' then go to [the page](https://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/).

Answer (score 0):

Since a `src` change cannot be transformed on a single IMGElement, you need to create all your images upfront. Such will also prevent to see flashes of *white* when the next image is still being loaded by the browser.

Use GPU accelerated CSS `transition` and CSS `transform`, to animate your `opacity` property of your images.
Use **JS just to toggle a CSS `".is-active"` class**, that in return will fade your images:

```js
jQuery(($) => {

  const images = [
    "https://placehold.it/150x150/0bf?text=One",
    "https://placehold.it/300x150/bf0?text=Two",
    "https://placehold.it/300x150/fb0?text=Three",
  ];
  
  const $img = $(images.map((src) => $("<img>", {src: src})[0])); // Generate IMGs
  const $gal = $("#images").append($img); // Append them to a parent
  const tot = images.length;
  const anim = () => $img.removeClass("is-active").eq(idx).addClass("is-active");
  let idx = 0;

  $("#prev").on("click", () => {
    idx = (idx + tot - 1) % tot;
    anim();
  });

  $("#next").on("click", () => {
    idx = (idx + 1) % tot;
    anim();
  });

  anim(); // Init Animate!

});
```

```css
#images {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#images img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain; /* Scale image to fit parent element */
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s; /* Use GPU accelerated properties */
}

#images img.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>
<button type="button" id="prev">&larr;</button>
<button type="button" id="next">&rarr;</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```